# ¿Reciben un nombre especial los gerundios de los verbos? ¿Se pueden expresar acciones en desarrollo sin usar el gerundio?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales, aspecto-gramatical, tiempos-verbales-progresivos

Creo observar un patrón en torno a los tiempos verbales (en indicativo) pero no sé sí estaré en lo correcto. Sin usar definiciones exactas:

Observo que los verbos simples son siempre "**Imperfectos**" (indican una acción cuyo inicio o final no está definido). 
**Ej**:

> Yo *cocino*
>   Yo *cociné*
>   Yo *cocinaré*

Observo cuando el verbo principal es participio son siempre "**Perfectos**" (indican que la acción ya ha concluido). 
**Ej**:

> He *cocinado*
>   Habiendo *cocinado*
>   Estando *cocinado*
>   Siendo *cocinado*
>   Habiendo sido *cocinado*

Finalmente cuando el verbo principal es gerundio indican una acción que está en desarrollo.
**Ej**:

> Estoy *cocinando*
>   Estuve *cocinando*
>   Estaré *cocinando*
>   Estando *cocinando*
>   He estado *cocinando*

Preguntas:

1- ¿Es éste patrón correcto? Lo he probado con más de una decena de verbos y siempre me funciona pero por supuesto no estoy seguro.

2- ¿Qué título reciben los verbos "en desarrollo"?  Tenemos "Perfectos" para indicar las acciones completadas e "Imperfectas" para indicar las cuyo inicio o fin no está claro pero no encuentro qué título llevan los que claramente están en desarrollo.

3- Si el patrón es correcto, ¿también aplicará para el subjuntivo?

4- ¿Se pueden usar otros tiempos verbales aparte del gerundio para expresar acciones en desarrollo?

Comment: Tus verbos principales en tus ejemplos no son *cocinado* y *cocinando*, sino **Haber** y **Estar**. El participio "cocinado" funciona como un adjetivo en "Estando cocinado" y como adverbio en "Estando cocinando".

"He cocinado" es perfecto porque "He" es perfecto. "Estuve cocinando" también es perfecto porque "Estuve" es perfecto. Estando cocinado" no es perfecto ni imperfecto: es un adjetivo modificado por un adverbio.

Comment: Los verbos simples no son siempre imperfectos.  El nombre completo de la forma *cociné* es la *primera persona singular del pretérito **perfecto** simple*.  De ahí empieza parte de la confusión.  Y a pesar de que los tiempos como *cocinaré* son imperfectos, ello no quiere decir que estén en progreso, solo que la acción no representa algo completada con respecto a otro tiempo: son aoristos –o indefinidos–, porque no nos concierne el tiempo en que desarrolla la acción.

Comment: La diferencia entre *he cocinado* y *estoy cocinando* es que el primero es un **tiempo** verbal y el segundo es una **perífrasis** verbal. Mientras que los tiempos verbales pueden ser perfectos, imperfectos, pluscuamperfectos, etc., las perífrasis tienen su propia clasificación. Las perífrasis construidas con gerundios suelen indicar "desarrollo", y se denominan *durativas*.

Comment: @Yay Gracias por su comentario, pero me sucitan otras dudas: 1- ¿Como distingo entre un ´tiempo verbal y una ´perífrasis verbal´?  No entiendo como es que sabes que **he cocinado** es tiempo verbal mientras que **estoy cocinando** no lo es.

Comment: @Yay Otra duda, dices que perífrasis con gerundios **suelen** indicar "desarrollo"; ¿Me podrías ayudar con algún ejemplo en la cual dicha perífrasis con gerundio **no** indica desarrollo?  Además habrá alguna otra forma de señalar que la accion esta "en desarrollo" sin usar gerundios?

Comment: @CarlosK La respuesta rápida sería que solo *haber* puede funcionar como auxiliar en un tiempo verbal. Si se admite que *estoy cocinando* es un tiempo verbal, entonces también se tendrían que incluir *sigo cocinando*, *llevo cocinando* y todas las demás perífrasis existentes. Puedes leer sobre perífrasis en la [§ 28](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=buSUphzUgccgmyjd) de la [NGLE](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica), y sobre su relación con los tiempos verbales en la [§ 28.5](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SMOUtHBHUciOXVzS).

Comment: @CarlosK Digo *suelen* para dejar abierta una "vía de escape" en caso de que a alguien se le ocurra un contraejemplo. Según tengo entendido, todas las perífrasis de gerundio indican desarrollo o duración.

Comment: @yay Muchisimas gracias, creo que ya me esta quedando claro.  Solamente una ultima molestia, ¿conoces de alguna otro forma en que sea posible indicar que una acción esta ´en desarrollo´ aparte del perífrasis de gerundio?  Usando gerundios es la única manera que se me ocurre, ¿habrá otra?

Comment: @guifa Disculpando el abuso, pero podría ser tan amable de ver si ahora estoy aplicando correctamente los tiempos en http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18731/13005  todavia estoy inseguro si estoy nombrando correctamente los tiempos y especialmente en donde el perífrasis parece indicar tiempo.

Comment: @SantiagoTórtora Todos los tiempos compuestos son perfectos, incluso cuando la forma del verbo haber usada es imperfecta. El caso que das (*he*) es un ejemplo; es el presente y, por tanto, imperfecto, pero forma al pretérito perfecto como auxiliar en los tiempos compuestos.

Answer (score 1):

> <sub>Respuesta basada en los comentarios a la pregunta, especialmente los de [Yay](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/11511/yay). Se marca como *community wiki* para que cualquiera pueda aportar a la misma.</sub>

La diferencia entre he cocinado y estoy cocinando es que el primero es un *tiempo* verbal y el segundo es una *perífrasis* verbal. Mientras que los tiempos verbales pueden ser perfectos, imperfectos, pluscuamperfectos, etc., las perífrasis tienen su propia clasificación. Las perífrasis construidas con gerundios suelen indicar "desarrollo", y se denominan **durativas**.

Para distinguir entre un tiempo y una perífrasis verbal, la respuesta rápida sería que solo *haber* puede funcionar como auxiliar en un tiempo verbal. Si se admite que *estoy cocinando* es un tiempo verbal, entonces también se tendrían que incluir *sigo cocinando*, *llevo cocinando* y todas las demás perífrasis existentes. Puedes leer sobre perífrasis en el [capítulo 28](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=buSUphzUgccgmyjd) de la *[Nueva gramática de la lengua española](http://www.rae.es/recursos/gramatica/nueva-gramatica)*, y sobre su relación con los tiempos verbales en el [apartado 28.5](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=SMOUtHBHUciOXVzS).

Estas perífrasis, por supuesto, se pueden conjugar también en subjuntivo: *esté cocinando*, *estuviera cocinando*, etc.

Por último, para responder a tu última pregunta en los comentarios, el gerundio no es el único tiempo verbal con el que se puede expresar una acción en desarrollo. Se me ocurre el siguiente ejemplo:

> —¿Y tú, a qué te dedicas para vivir?
>   Pues soy arquitecto.

En el ejemplo, *dedicas* es presente de indicativo, pero denota algo que está en desarrollo: la dedicación de la persona para subsistir. El interlocutor se está dedicando a la arquitectura en ese momento de su vida, como algo en proceso: empezó en el pasado y aún no ha terminado. Por supuesto, el lenguaje es interpretable y hay quien interpreta el presente de indicativo como que expresa hechos puntuales y hay quien lo interpreta como acciones en progreso. Por ejemplo, en la frase:

> Necesito hablar contigo.

¿Ese "necesito" en presente es puntual o en progreso? Se podría interpretar como "estoy necesitando hablar contigo", dado que es algo que venías necesitando previamente y aún sientes esa necesidad. Este hecho se conoce como el **presente progresivo**, y se ve aún más claro en ejemplos como:

> —A ver, ¿qué pasa aquí? *[="qué está pasando"]*
>   —¡Suéltame, me haces daño! *[="me estás haciendo daño"]*

El presente progresivo se puede consultar en el [apartado 23.5](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wufShHIKqaUHfiHs) de la *Nueva gramática*.

Comment: En Argentina se ha vuelto común decir cosas como "Estoy necesitando hablar con vos" y, en ciertos medios, formas como "Estaría necesitando comer algo ya mismo" o "No me estaría quedando claro qué pasa", que interpreto como exageraciones humorísticas de formas que aparecen en titulares periodísticos, por ejemplo. ¿Existe esto en otros dialectos?

Comment: @pablodf76 es genial cómo en Argentina se juega con el lenguaje. Aquí en España a veces se ponen de moda expresiones exageradas similares, pero la que comentas la verdad es que no la había escuchado nunca.

Comment: Del Twitter de un conocido presentador televisivo, por la mañana: "[Como que mi cuerpo no estaría entendiendo la orden de levantarse.](https://twitter.com/rialjorge/status/791607492329570304)" :-)

Answer (score 0):

En respuesta a su pregunta 4), claro que es posible utilizar otras formas verbales, aparte del gerundio, para expresar 'acciones - o procesos - en curso de desarrollo'. Un simple infinitivo ya puede servir para eso: en *Estoy oyéndola **tocar** el piano*, por ejemplo, el infinitivo *tocar* ya expresa una acción en curso de desarrollo. Lo mismo cabe decir del presente simple en casos como *¿Qué **haces**? **Leo** el periódico* y de cualquier imperfecto, como en *Cuando yo **subía** hace un momento, **bajaba** el jefe hecho una furia*.

En cambio, la respuesta a su primera pregunta es parcialmente negativa debido a que el 'patrón' que Ud. percibe  - y que, según Ud., le 'funciona' - no puede 'funcionarle' **del todo** bien, porque, en lo que respecta a los tiempos 'simples' (no así en lo tocante a los perfectos y 'progresivos') **no** es exacto. Basta añadir adverbiales apropiados a tiempos como *cocino*, *cociné* o *cocinaré* para que pasen a describir acciones cuyos inicios y finales están temporalmente definidos. Si, por ejemplo, en respuesta a la pregunta *¿Qué **hiciste** esta mañana?* Ud. dice *De nueve a diez **cociné**, de diez a once **limpié** la casa, de once a doce **hice** gimnasia y de doce a dos **paseé** por la playa*, todos esos indefinidos denotan acciones que tienen un principio y un final perfectamente delimitados por los adverbiales de tiempo correspondientes. Lo mismo ocurre si utiliza futuros simples; la acción no habrá ocurrido aún, naturalmente, pero puede estar perfectamente delimitada: si en respuesta a la pregunta *¿Qué **harás** esta tarde?* Ud. dice *De cuatro a seis **leeré** una novela, de seis a ocho **tocaré** el piano, y de ocho a diez **veré** alguna película en la tele* todos esos futuros simples denotan acciones futuras de carácter 'durativo' y perfectamente delimitadas. Finalmente, también ocurre así en presente, en realidad, aunque el presente se presta a describir, o bien estados de cosas, procesos o actividades persistentes, o bien eventos o acciones que pueden ser puntuales pero que se repiten habitualmente en períodos de tiempo largos en relación con la duración efectiva de cada una de esos eventos o acciones, o incluso ilimitados, pero eso no convierte a las acciones mismas en temporalmente ilimitadas. Si Ud. trabaja en un restaurante y dice, por ejemplo, *Yo hoy **cocino** de ocho a diez*, los dos circunstanciales de tiempo obligan al verbo *cocino* a referirse a una actividad que, obviamente, tiene principio y fin, independientemente de que haya empezado ya y esté en curso o vaya a empezar más tarde. Si quita el adverbial *hoy* y dice solo *Yo **cocino** de ocho a diez*, según la situación en que lo diga, esa oración puede significar que hoy lo hace en esas horas o que habitualmente lo hace en esas horas y por tanto volverá a hacerlo en esa franja horaria cada vez que le toque cocinar. El presente expresa entonces actividades habituales, reiteradas, pero eso **no** las convierte en actividades de límites temporales indefinidos. Si, por último, omite Ud. cualquier especificación respecto a la duración de las actividades o procesos y dice únicamente *Yo **cocino***, entonces, evidentemente, el presente *cocino* predica de Ud. una **propiedad** persistente, la de ser capaz de, o aficionado a, o encargado oficial de, las tareas relacionadas con la cocina, y en ese caso, efectivamente, la actividad/propiedad de 'cocinar' que el verbo describe no tiene principio ni fin específicamente expresados. Pero, como ve, **no es exacto decir que los tiempos simples describen actividades ilimitadas en el tiempo**. Cualquier forma verbal que pueda ser modificada por un complemento circunstancial que exprese duración o un intervalo de tiempo con un principio y un fin, por definición, está expresando eventos en curso de desarrollo con principio y fin especificados.

En cuanto a su pregunta 3), como ya hemos visto, el 'patrón' **no es del todo correcto**, pero lo dicho antes acerca del indicativo también se aplica al presente y al imperfecto de subjuntivo si llevan adverbiales de 'tiempo' apropiados. Si Ud. le dice a su vecino *Cuando **toque** Ud. el piano entre las tres y las cuatro de la tarde, por favor ponga la sordina. Mi padre duerme la siesta a esas horas*, obviamente el presente de subjuntivo *toque* es capaz de denotar una actividad durativa con un principio y un final claramente especificados.

Por último, en cuanto a cómo denominar a los verbos según el tipo de situaciones, eventos, procesos, actividades, 'logros' o 'actos' que describan, debe utilizar términos/conceptos que precisen, no el 'tiempo', sino el 'aspecto' verbal, bien el inherente a cada verbo en sí mismo, o el que pueda adquirir si va acompañado por complementos o modificadores que lo alteren. Una terminología bastante extendida es la que opone los predicados verbales 'estáticos', que denotan 'propiedades' o ‘estados’, a los predicados 'dinámicos', que denotan ‘procesos’ (e.g., *llover*), por un lado, y ‘actividades’ (*esquiar, enseñar inglés, vender casas, tocar el piano*,…), por otro, todos los cuales admiten modificadores que pueden precisar su duración, frente a **otros** predicados 'dinámicos' que ya expresan 'cambios de estado', sean ‘sucesos puntuales’ (*estallar, aparecer, llegar*,…), ‘logros’ (*heredar, encontrar, ver, oír*,…) o ‘actos’ que lo son únicamente en el momento en que culminan (i.e., predicados 'télicos', del Gr. 'télos' = 'fin') y que, por tanto, no 'duran' y rechazan modificadores que expresen duración (aunque esos 'cambios de estado' sí 'llevan tiempo', y en consecuencia aceptan modificadores como *en dos horas, en dos semanas*, etc. en casos como *Consiguió acabar el libro **en dos horas/en dos semanas***, etc.). Si busca en Google términos como 'aspecto verbal', 'télico', 'atélico', y los demás que le he mencionado, le saldrán muchas páginas en las que podrá informarse más sobre este asunto.