# Tiempos verbales aplicados a "cocinar"

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales, aspecto-gramatical

Estoy intentando aprender correctamente los tiempos verbales. ¿Podrían por favor verificar si he aplicado correctamente los tiempos al verbo **cocinar**? Además hay un par de tiempos que no logró identificar o quizas no sean tiempos sino perífrasis.

**Tiempos Simples:**

- *Cocino* =  Presente simple
- *Cociné* = Pretérito perfecto simple
- *Cocinaba* = Pretérito imperfecto
- *Cocinaré* = Futuro simple
- *Cocinaría* = Futuro condicional

**Tiempos Compuestos:**

- *He cocinado* = Pretérito perfecto
- *Había cocinado* = Pretérito pluscuamperfecto
- *Hube cocinado* = Pretérito anterior
- *Habiendo cocinado* = ¿Será un perífrasis con gerundio y no un tiempo verbal?
- *Habré cocinado* = Futuro perfecto
- *He estado cocinando* = ¿El ***he*** parece indicar que es perfecto pero ***estado cocinando*** parece ser una perífrasis con gerundio?
- *Habría cocinado* = Futuro condicional perfecto

Answer (score 4):

Para todos aquellos que tengan dudas sobre los tiempos verbales, mi recomendación es consultar en la RAE el infinitivo del verbo. Junto a este aparece un botón de "conjugar" que permite acceder a la conjugación de los tiempos simples de dicho verbo:

[image: Conjugación de cocinar]

Para acceder a los tiempos compuestos, basta con consultar los tiempos simples correspondientes del verbo haber, y añadir detrás el participio del verbo principal. Para conocer la correspondencia, se puede consultar la siguiente tabla (válida tanto para indicativo como para subjuntivo y las formas no personales):

```
tiempo compuesto         tiempo simple verbo haber
--------------------------------------------------
infinitivo compuesto     infinitivo simple
gerundio compuesto       gerundio simple
pret. perf. compuesto    presente
pret. pluscuamperfecto   pret. imperfecto
pret. anterior           pret. perfecto simple
futuro compuesto         futuro simple
condicional compuesto    condicional simple
```

- Definición de **[cocinar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9aukAUD)**.
- Definición de **[haber](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jv4Frsm)**.

Sobre el tiempo "he estado cocinando", puedes consultar la conjugación de "[estar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GnJiqdL)" para los tiempos simples, o la mencionada de "haber" para los compuestos de "estar". El DPD dice lo siguiente sobre la construcción en la entrada sobre "[estar](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=estar)":

> ***estar* + gerundio**. Forma una perífrasis durativa, que presenta la acción en el curso de su desarrollo.

Comment: Muchas gracias, no conocía ese recurso de la RAE, me será de gran ayuda para aprender acerca de la conjugación.

Comment: Sin embargo, con "he estado cocinando" sigo algo inseguro.  Fui a leer en los recursos que me indico.  Entorno a ["estar"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=estar) tal como indicas, el inciso 7 aclara que estar + gerundio forma una perífrasis durativa.   Entorno a ["haber"](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=estar) Incisos 34 y 35 muestran las conjugaciones Estar y Haber pero no especifica más allá.  Perdone mi ignorancia, entonces en la oración: "Hoy he estado cocinando todo el día."  El tiempo es Pretérito Perfecto y además tiene un perífrasis durativa. ¿Será correcta está afirmación?

Comment: @CarlosK deberías crear una nueva pregunta con tu último comentario. Así como está sólo Carlos Alejo se enteró que tenías esta duda y tal vez no ha tenido tiempo de responder.

Comment: @DGaleano Gracias por la sugerencia!  Me aseguraré de hacerlo.

Comment: @DGaleano Tal como sugeriste, y para quien más le sea de utilidad, he planteado el tema de "**he estado cocinado**" como una nueva pregunta.  Puedes encontrarla [aquí](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/18770/es-he-estado-cocinando-un-tiempo-compuesto-o-per%C3%ADfrasis-o-ambas).

Comment: @CarlosK en el momento en que vi tu comentario no podía responder, y luego se me olvidó (tiendo a ser despistado). Es mucho mejor que las sucesivas dudas se planteen como nuevas preguntas, así le damos más vida al sitio, que le hace falta.