# ¿Es "he estado cocinando" un tiempo compuesto, una perífrasis o ambas?

Tags: gramática, verbos, tiempos-verbales

Tengo dificultad clasificando la oración: "*Hoy **he estado cocinando** todo el día.*"

Por un lado, al consultar la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=haber) (vease el inciso **3** "*verbo auxiliar*") la presencia del verbo **he** + **estado** indica que forma "los tiempos compuestos de conjugación". Por ello diría que está oración es **Pretérito Perfecto**.

Sin embargo, la [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=estar) (vease el inciso **7** "*estar + gerundio*") indica que **estado cocinando** "Forma una perífrasis durativa, que presenta la acción en el curso de su desarrollo".  Esto me hace pensar que la oración no es pretérito perfecto sino consiste de una **perífrasis durativa**.

¿Entonces como clasifico esta oración?
¿Simplemente como **Pretérito Perfecto** o como una **Perífrasis Durativa**?
¿Puedo usar *ambas clasificaciones a la vez* afirmando que su tiempo es Pretérito Perfecto pero incluye una Perífrasis Durativa? 
 ¿Debo darle alguna otra clasificación?

Agradezco cualquier ayuda para aclarar mi confusión.

Answer (score 1):

El *tiempo* es **pretérito perfecto** a secas. Lo de «**durativa**» respecto a la perífrasis especifica el *aspecto* (una categoría distinta al tiempo, como lo es el modo, el número, etc.).

Comment: ¡Muchisimas gracias por la aclaración!